# how to prolong the session even after the user closed the browser?

Tags: php

I need a way to maintain session even after the user closed the browser (  until user click logout ) **without storing session in the database**.

What is the best way to do that ?

Could I store username + password ( hashed ) in a cookie ?

Comment: I am sure he means, that he needs the way for user to stay loggined. Most sites allow auto-login on base of coockies settings. I'd became mad if I need to enter my login and pass on each forum I visit.

Answer (score 1):

Save in cookie with large expiry time (say 1 month or so).
Need not be a password hashed, just some identification hash, that is stored in DB as well as userside (in comparison), so that you can compare.

Answer (score 1):

When the user log in, you should generate a random token and 1) save it in your database, 2) set a cookie with username and this random token.

Then, you should create a function that takes this cookie and matches the token with the one in your DB. If the token is the same, you should start a session and generate a new one.

Use a random token and not the password, otherwise it will be always the same.

Remember that your "is the user logged in" function has to check first if the session is open, otherwise it will repeat this process for every page the user visits.